# Get the detailed text of the window android in AccessibilityEvent

Tags: android, accessibility

i use this code to get text of event:

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent"+event.getEventType());
        if(event.getEventType()==AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED){
             Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent"+event);
```

example: when i in this screen:

[image]

The `result` in run is:

```
D/TestAccessibleService: onAccessibilityEvent EventType: TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED; EventTime: 360090279; PackageName: com.android.settings; MovementGranularity: 0; Action: 0 [ ClassName: com.android.settings.DeviceAdminAdd; Text: [Người quản trị thiết bị]; ContentDescription: null; ItemCount: -1; CurrentItemIndex: -1; IsEnabled: true; IsPassword: false; IsChecked: false; IsFullScreen: true; Scrollable: false; BeforeText: null; FromIndex: -1; ToIndex: -1; ScrollX: -1; ScrollY: -1; MaxScrollX: -1; MaxScrollY: -1; AddedCount: -1; RemovedCount: -1; ParcelableData: null ]; recordCount: 0
```

what i need is text it in green circle (**already in** `result`:`Text: [Người quản trị thiết bị]`) and all text in red circle,I haven't got the text in red circle,how can i get the text in red circle. Please help me. Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this an AccessibilityService?

The reason you are getting that text is that your [AccessibilityFocus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service#focus-types) is on that element. If you enable accessibility and swipe from left to right the focus will change to the "next" element - keep doing that until you focus on the correct element.

If you want to SET the accessibility focus on that element you can call:

```
findViewById(R.id.{elementId}).sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
```

But it's not recommended you do that in production.

Comment: I have accessibility service and have enabled it manually. Is there a way to revoke (disable) it automatically by code. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately not if you want to put your app on the Google Play store. You would need to have the WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission, which requires your app to be a system app. http://androidpermissions.org/android-permission-WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS/